# Distance between $A= \{(x,\frac{1}{x}) \mid x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \}$ and $B= \mathbb{R \times \{0\}}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $A= \{(x,\frac{1}{x}) \mid x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \}$ and $B= \mathbb{R \times \{0\}}$. Determine the distance between $A$ and $B$ using the Euclidean metric and the discrete metric.

Letting $(x,y) \in A$ and $(x',y') \in B$ I have that $y'=0$ and $y\ne0$. However I cannot seem to be able to find any upper bound for the distance... I have that $\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2} = \sqrt{(x-x')^2+y^2} \geqslant \sqrt{(x-x')^2}$, but this doesn't seem to help. How should I approach this?

Comment: It's about he infimum of the distances, so upperbounds don't matter.

Answer (score 3):

In the Euclidean distance, for all $n \in \Bbb N^+$, $a_n:=(n,\frac1n) \in A$ and $b_n:=(n,0) \in B$ and $d(a_n, b_n)=\frac1n \to 0$ so that $d(A,B)=0$.

In the discrete metric $d(A,B)=1$ for any pair of disjoint sets.

Comment: Where is the limit for $\frac{1}{n}$ coming from? Why are we interested what happens when $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @DanielLi We want to know it can be made as close to $0$ as we like, so no value $>0$ can be a lower bound. The limit tells us that.